# PIC16F887 external interrupt(RB0/INT) not working

Tags: assembly, interrupt, pic

Here is the task: The program writes 2 digits number into
the EEPROM, and lights up LEDs 6, 7 and 8 when writing is completed. When the switch is pressed, LED 1 should light up.

My problem: When I press the switch, LED 1 is not light up. The part where writing to EEPROM and lighting up LEDs are working well. When I run the code in MPLAB IDE v8.88, only LEDs 6,7 and 8 are lighted up.

I have tried to change "goto $" to "sleep and loop back to sleep" but it is still not working. Any problem with my code? I am just new to assembly language and PIC. Thanks.

Here is my code:

```
#include <p16F887.inc>
__CONFIG    _CONFIG1, _LVP_OFF & _FCMEN_OFF & _IESO_OFF & _BOR_OFF & _CPD_OFF & _CP_OFF & _MCLRE_OFF & _PWRTE_ON & _WDT_OFF & _INTRC_OSC_NOCLKOUT
__CONFIG    _CONFIG2, _WRT_OFF & _BOR21V

 org 0000h
 goto Start
 org 0004h
 goto Interrupt

 Start:
 ;write ID code into EEPROM
 bsf STATUS,RP0             ;goes to bank 1
 movlw 78h                  ;moves address to working register
 movwf EEADR                ;moves address to EEADR
 movlw d'24'                ;moves number to working register
 movwf EEDATA               ;moves number from working register to EEDATA               
 bsf STATUS,RP1             ;goes to bank 3
 bsf EECON1,2               ;enables a write operation
 bcf INTCON,7               ;disables global interrupt

 ;safe combination
 movlw 55h                  ;'safe combination'
 movwf EECON2
 movlw 0AAh
 movwf EECON2
 bsf EECON1,1               ;starts the write operation

 ;write verify 
 btfsc EECON1,1             ;wait for WR bit to clear (wait for writing to complete)
 goto $-1

 ;light up LED 6,7,8
 bsf STATUS,RP0 
 bcf STATUS,RP1             ;select register bank 1

 bsf TRISB,0                ;make RB0 input

 bcf TRISD,5                ;make RD5 output
 bcf TRISD,6                ;make RD6 output
 bcf TRISD,7                ;make RD7 output
 bcf STATUS,RP0             ;select register bank 0
 bsf PORTD,5                ;turn on LED RD5
 bsf PORTD,6                ;turn on LED RD6
 bsf PORTD,7                ;turn on LED RD7

 bsf STATUS,RP0             ;select register bank 1
 bcf INTCON,INTF            ;clear external INT flag
 bsf OPTION_REG,INTEDG      ;interrupt on positive edge         
 bsf INTCON,INTE            ;enables interrupts on RBO/INT
 bsf INTCON,GIE             ;enable global interrupts

 goto $                     ;wait here

 Interrupt: 
 ;interrupt service routine:
 ;light up LED 1
 bsf STATUS,RP0             ;select register bank 1     
 bcf TRISD,0                ;make RD0 output
 bcf STATUS,RP0             ;select register bank 0  
 bsf PORTD,0                ;turn on LED RD0

 ;at the end of interrupt service routine
 bcf INTCON,INTF            ;clear external INT flag
 retfie                     ;end of interrupt routine

 end
```

Comment: At first view, your code looks correct. Are you sure the switch is wired correctly (weak pull-down and pull-up when pressed) ? You can also put the code for LED 1 into the main code, just to check it actually lights it.

Comment: @ElderBug The switch has weak pull-up when not pressed. I have added the line " bsf OPTION_REG,7" in the main code to disable weak pull-up. Also, the code for LED 1 is working fine.

Comment: The internal pull-ups are disabled by default. The question is more about the external wiring. Did you wire the switch yourself ? Or is it part of a pre-built board or smth ?

Comment: @ElderBug It is part of a pre-build board

Comment: Try clearing the ANSELH bit 5. RB0 is AN12, and is an analog pin by default.

Comment: @ElderBug I cleared but it is still not working

Comment: Mmmh, I said it wrong, I actually meant bit 4 (5th bit), sorry about that. Did you clear bit 4 ?

Comment: @ElderBug Yes, I cleared bit 4, still not working